# The number of elements of order 2 in $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2q})$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p,q$ be distinct primes. Let's consider the multiplicative group of the *units* of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2q}$, namely $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2q})$.

> How many elements of order $2$ does $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2q})$ have?

---

My attempt:
$p^{2}q|(a-1)(a+1)$.

Now the possibley combinations are

i) $p^{2}|(a-1)$ and $q|(a+1)$ so $a=p^2+1 $ and $a=(q-1)$.

ii) $p^{2}|(a+1)$ and $q|(a-1)$. So $a = p^2-1 $ and $a=(q+1)$.

iii)$ p|(a-1)$ and $pq|(a+1)$ so $a= (p+1)$ and $a=pq-1$

iv) $p|(a+1)$ and $pq|(a-1)$ so $a =p-1$ and $a =pq+1$

v)  $p^2q|(a+1)$ so $a =p^2q-1$

This has been my attempt.

Comment: Are both primes odd?

Comment: This is a survey of the elements of order $2$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ according to the value of $n$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32895/750041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one element of order $2$ which you missed:

$p^2q|(a-1)$ and so $a=1$.

Otherwise your attempt is OK.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then:

$$U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2q})\cong U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{q}) \tag 1$$

So, your problem boils down to finding the elements of order $2$ of $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})$ and $U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$.

1. Let's first assume $p,q$ odd primes. Then, both $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})$ and $U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$ are cyclic of even order; it follows that they both have $\varphi(2)=1$ element of order $2$ ($\varphi$ is Euler's function), say $a$ and $b$ respectively:

   > therefore, if $p,q$ are distinct odd primes, then $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$ has three elements of order $2$, namely $(a,1)$, $(1,b)$ and $(a,b)$; by $(1)$, so has $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2q})$.

We are left with the two cases $(p,q)=(2,odd\space prime)$ and $(p,q)=(odd\space prime,2)$:

2. If $(p,q)=(2,odd\space prime)$, then $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})=U(\mathbb{Z}_{4})\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})=\{1,3\}\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$; let $b$ the only element of order $2$ of $U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$; we have that:

   > the elements of order $2$ of $U(\mathbb{Z}_{4})\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$ are: $(1,b)$, $(3,1)$ and $(3,b)$. So, $U(\mathbb{Z}_{4q})$ has three elements of order $2$.
3. If $(p,q)=(odd\space prime,2)$, then $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{q})=U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{2})=U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})\times \{1\}$; let $a$ the only element of order $2$ of $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})$; we have that:

   > the only element of order $2$ of $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})\times U(\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ is $(a,1)$. So, $U(\mathbb{Z}_{2p^2})$ has just one element of order $2$.

This completes the survey for $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ in the case $n=p^2q, p\ne q$.